# UIButton with dynamic font size support

Tags: ios, dynamic, fonts, uibutton, size

I'm trying to use dynamic font size on a `UIButton`. But if I increase the font size, the text on the button gets truncated to "...".

Any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: You're right, I was setting fixed height constraint 

Answer (score 3):

You can get the [UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel) of `UIButton` by

```
let btn = UIButton() ....
if let label = btn.textLabel {
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true // Adjust font size automatically
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5 //< The minimum font size scale factor 
}
```

#### Reference

1. [adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth)
2. [minimumscalefactor property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620544-minimumscalefactor)
3. [UILabel reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel)

Answer (score 0):

Use a constraint with height greater than or equal